# PyFunctionObject crash the programm in Py_Finalize if it has being set item in PyTuple

Tags: python, c++, python-c-api

I need get list of function name and signatures by python file.
Python function `inspect.signature` can get me function signature.
But `inspect.signature` need a function object (`PyFunctionObject`).
`inspect.getmembers` can return such object.
But if I set `PyFunctionObject` as item in `PyTuple`, when `Py_Finalize` is executed - I get error.
Also, I'm using Qt.

So line `PyTuple_SetItem(pFuncLink_arg, 0, pGetmember_tupleList);` result error.

Code:.

```
PyObject *pName, *pModule;
PyObject *pInspect_module_name, *pInspect_module;
PyObject *pGetmember_function, *pGetmember_call_args, *pGetmembers_reply, *pGetsignature_function, *pGetmember_itemList, *pGetmember_tupleList;
PyObject *pFuncName, *pFuncLink_arg, *pFuncSign;

Py_Initialize();

QFileInfo fileInfo(QFile("X:/Projects/p-text.py"));
QString absPath = fileInfo.absolutePath();

QString fileName = fileInfo.baseName();

PyObject* sysPath = PySys_GetObject((char*)"path"); 
PyObject* programName = PyUnicode_FromString(absPath.toAscii());
PyList_Append(sysPath, programName);

pName = PyUnicode_FromString(fileName.toLatin1());
pModule = PyImport_Import(pName);
Py_DECREF(pName);

if (pModule != NULL){
    pInspect_module_name = PyUnicode_DecodeFSDefault("inspect");
    pInspect_module = PyImport_Import(pInspect_module_name);
    pGetmember_function = PyObject_GetAttrString(pInspect_module, "getmembers");    
    pGetsignature_function = PyObject_GetAttrString(pInspect_module, "signature");

    pGetmember_call_args = PyTuple_New(1);
    PyTuple_SetItem(pGetmember_call_args, 0, pModule);
    pGetmembers_reply = PyObject_CallObject(pGetmember_function, pGetmember_call_args);

    if (pGetmembers_reply){
        Py_ssize_t const num_args = PyList_Size(pGetmembers_reply);
        for (Py_ssize_t i = 0; i < num_args; ++i){
            pGetmember_itemList = PyList_GetItem(pGetmembers_reply, i);
            pGetmember_tupleList =  PyTuple_GetItem(pGetmember_itemList, 1);

            if (PyFunction_Check(pGetmember_tupleList)){
                pFuncName =  PyTuple_GetItem(pGetmember_itemList, 0);
                QString funcName = PyObjectToString(pFuncName);
                    Py_DECREF(pFuncName);

                pFuncLink_arg = PyTuple_New(1);
                PyTuple_SetItem(pFuncLink_arg, 0, pGetmember_tupleList);

                pFuncSign = PyObject_CallObject(pGetsignature_function, pFuncLink_arg);

                if (pFuncSign == NULL) {
                    if (PyErr_Occurred()) {
                        PyErr_Print(); 
                    }
                    return;
                }

                QString funcSign = PyObjectToString(pFuncSign);

                Py_DECREF(pFuncSign);

                cout<<funcSign.toStdString()<<endl;
            }

            Py_DECREF(pGetmember_tupleList);
            Py_DECREF(pGetmember_itemList);
        }
    }
    Py_DECREF(pInspect_module_name);
    Py_DECREF(pInspect_module);
    Py_DECREF(pGetmember_function);
    Py_DECREF(pGetsignature_function);
    Py_DECREF(pGetmember_call_args);
}
else {
    PyErr_Print();
}

Py_Finalize();
```

`Py_Finalize()` throws an error 
"project_name.exe has triggered a breakpoint"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reference counting error.

[`PyTuple_GetItem`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/tuple.html#c.PyTuple_GetItem) returns a "borrowed reference". You don't own `pGetmember_tupleList`.

`PyTuple_SetItem` (find it at the same link...) "steals a reference", i.e. assumes you do own `pGetmember_tupleList` before the call but you don't own it after the call.

You need to add a `Py_INCREF(pGetmember_tupleList)` after getting it.

---

You have a separate, related reference counting error with `pFuncName` - you decref a borrowed reference that you don't own. I suspect there are probably other reference counting errors here too...

---

You also have no error checking; almost every Python call should be followed by a check to see if it raised an exception (usually for a `NULL` pointer).